# PhysicsLayout ImageView goes off bounds when flinging too hard

Tags: java, android, android-layout, github

**Hi**

I tried `GitHub`'s `PhysicsLayout` (https://github.com/Jawnnypoo/PhysicsLayout/) and I came across this problem,

*When enabled flinging and tried to throw the ImageView outside the screen, the ImageView goes off bounds*

**Here's my code**:

```
  public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ball;  
    PhysicsRelativeLayout physicsLayout;
    private int ballX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        physicsLayout = (PhysicsRelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.physics_layout);
        physicsLayout.getPhysics().enablePhysics();

        physicsLayout.getPhysics().enableFling();


        ball = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ball);





    }
```

**XML**:

```
  <com.jawnnypoo.physicslayout.PhysicsRelativeLayout android:id="@+id/physics_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    app:physics="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ball"
        app:layout_shape="circle"
        app:layout_bodyType="dynamic"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/ball"
        android:layout_width="50dp" />



</com.jawnnypoo.physicslayout.PhysicsRelativeLayout>
```

**What causes this problem OR is it possible to fix it?**